# Are "Uzziah" and "Azariah" the name of the same king?

Tags: 2-kings, onomastics, 2-chronicles, kings

This is with reference to the two passages

[2 Chronicles 26](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Chronicles%2026&version=KJV):

> Then all the people of Judah took Uzziah, who was sixteen years old,
>   and made him king in the room of his father Amaziah.
>   2 He built
>   Eloth, and restored it to Judah, after that the king slept with his
>   fathers.
>   3 Sixteen years old was Uzziah when he began to reign, and
>   he reigned fifty and two years in Jerusalem. His mother's name also
>   was Jecoliah of Jerusalem.

and [2 Kings 15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Kings%2015&version=KJV):

> In the twenty and seventh year of Jeroboam king of
>   Israel began Azariah son of Amaziah king of Judah to reign.
>   2 Sixteen years old was he when he began to reign, and he reigned two
>   and fifty years in Jerusalem. And his mother's name was Jecholiah of
>   Jerusalem.

It seems pretty clear that both the chapters are referring to the same person?
Why then are the names mentioned different?

Answer (score 2):

could be two explanations or both

- one name is reigning name one is personal
- Hebrew word roots  "-z-z"  root of Uzziah and "-z-r"  root of Azariah , they both mean "strong" as playing on words.

  interesting note :

> Probably the best
> explanation is to regard one as a birth name and the other as a throne
> name taken at the time of his accession (A. Honeyman, “The Evidence
> for Regnal Names among the Hebrews,” JBL 67 [1948] 13–25); cf. other
> possible examples in the cases of Shallum-Jehoahaz (Jer 22:11),
> Eliakim-Jehoiakim (2 Kgs 23:34), and Mattaniah-Zedekiah (2 Kgs 24:17).
> The Chronicler’s consistent use of “Uzziah” in this chapter may be to
> facilitate distinguishing the king from the high priest Azariah
> (26:17, 20).

Comment: Good answer. And further, [2 Kings Chapter 15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Kings%2015&version=NIV) alone seems to use the names Azariah and Uzziah interchangeably. The first 2 verses introduce his 52 year reign in Jerusalem (Judah), and the next 3 kings of Israel are listed chronologically during his reign: Zechariah (38th yr of _Azariah_), Shallum (39th yr of _Uzziah_), and Menahem (39th yr of _Azariah_). (and some further mentions in the chapter too). As you read it, it's as if the author's switching the names on purpose to let you know it's the same person.

Answer (score 0):

Are “Uzziah” and “Azariah” the name of the same king? Why are the names different?

2 Chronicles 26 originated in the kingdom of Judah where he was known by his given name; Uzziah עזיה.

```
1 Then all the people of Judah took Uzziah, who was sixteen years old, and made him king in the room of his father Amaziah.
2 He built Eloth, and restored it to Judah, after that the king slept with his fathers.
3 Sixteen years old was Uzziah when he began to reign, and he reigned fifty and two years in Jerusalem. His mother's name also was Jecoliah of Jerusalem.
```

2 Kings 15 originated in Israel and he was called "Uzziah with a revelation in his heart"; עז(ר)יה

```
1 In the twenty and seventh year of Jeroboam king of Israel began Azariah son of Amaziah king of Judah to reign.
2 Sixteen years old was he when he began to reign, and he reigned two and fifty years in Jerusalem. And his mother's name was Jecholiah of Jerusalem.
```

Though not taught in seminaries, this practice is seen throughout scripture and practiced by rabbis. 'In the beginning' בראשית there was a covenant ברית with man אש at the heart בר(אש)ית .

Jeshua יהושׁע is yahweh יהוה of the flesh-- God incarnate (ה replaced with ע) with a marriage שׁ in his heart יהו(שׁ)ע Completing the prophecy of Emmanuel; God with us. (Mt 1:23 ) You didn't really think that Yeshua was just close enough to Emmanuel? They are two differen't names. The prophecy is fulfilled by just such word-play.

So the question is: Why would Uzziah be known as Uzziah of prophecy?

Uzziah was made king by the people. 2Ch 26:1
Jesus was made 'king' by the people. See the triumphal entry.

Uzziah was 16 when he was made king; the recommended age for marriage: 2Ch 26:1
Jesus obtained his bride through the cross. See Adams sleep/rib.

Uzziah did right according to his father: 2Ch 26:3
Jesus did right by his father. Father was "well-pleased"

Uzziah sought God according to the visions: 2Ch 265
Jesus sought God according to the prophecies.

Uzziah (Jesus) fought with the Philistines (sojourners) 
broke the wall of Gath (winepress/tribulation)
broke the wall of Jabneh (building of God/temple)
and the wall of Ashod (powerful/ the Jewish leaders)
the Arabians (mixed/Samaritans) of Gurbaal (dwelling of Baal/ Galilee of the gentiles?) etc.

Uzziah provided armor and weapons 
So did Jesus Eph 6

Uzziah  was lifted up to his destruction
Jesus was lifted up to his death

Uzziah went into the temple to burn
Christ went into the temple as the burnt offering

Uzziah became leprous
Jesus bore our sin

Uzziah was put outside the camp, as was Jesus

Azzariah (Uzziah of prophecy) was the name of the high priest.
Uzziah became known as Azzariah because Jesus became our high priest.

These are observations, not allegorical inventions.

As a side note, Uzziah also means the she-goat עז of her יה  .  The she-goat is the sacrifice for sin and trespass offerings. Le 4:28, Le 5:6.

And he became Azariah, the helper עזר of her יה.

Comment: Same father, same mother. Both 16, both ruled 52 years. No. they were the same person.

Comment: Okay, sorry I misread your post. Then they are the identical person. Suggestion: To ensure that your post is understood, say "They were the same person". I honestly don't know what you are trying to say, particularly in your second to last paragraph.

Answer (score -5):

Uzziah and Azariah are the same person because it quotes in Prophets and kings chapter twenty five "The long reign of Uzziah [also known as Azariah]

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange jlove, thanks for contributing! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is not of the typical quality expected on the site - what is "Prophets and kings"? I think there's a chance that your Bible *translation* has added the 'also known as Azariah' section to the text, and so it's worth double-checking your answer and explaining it a bit more clearly for us. Thanks!